# Opening another app from react-native iOS application

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I tried to use `Linking` from react native today in order to open mail app on ios from my one, something along the lines of

```
onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mail://')}
```

this didn't work and got me into googling spree, I got to [this article](https://medium.com/@vijayssundaram/how-to-deep-link-to-ios-7-mail-6c212bc79bd9) but it wasn't of any help, hence my question, how can we open another apps from react-native and what is the best way to find the url bit i.e. `mail://` for a specific app?

Update: using `mail:` as url didn't work out either

Comment: Hey @Ilja, try checking [this](http://johnsonsu.com/react-native-custom-url-scheme-launch-apps-using-linking/) and [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong scheme for interacting with the mail app. It's supposed to be `mailto`.

Try something like this:

```
Linking.openURL(mailto:email@example.com)
```

You should also make sure the URL you're trying is supported using the `Linking.canOpenURL` API.

It's also worth mentioning that some operations won't work in the simulator but only on a real device. **Sending an email is one of these operations** (another example is making a call using the `tel:` URL - will also work only on a real device).

Comment: Great! I was also thinking about `mailto` as the answer. Do you know how to call any app via Linking, are there any lists of acceptable schemes of apps?

Comment: There's a documentation for Apple apps which you can find here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899 but basically any app can expose supported schemes, so you'll need to check the official documentation for apps you're interested in (for example: there are hooks for Instagram, WhatsApp, etc.)